# How do you avoid creating multiple instances of an object with XML Deserialization?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I've got a class that when serialized to XML looks like this (generalized for simplicity):

```
<root>
  <resources>
    <resource name="foo" anotherattribute="value">data</resource>
    <resource name="bar" anotherattribute="value">more data</resource>
  </resource>
  <myobject name="objName">
    <resource name="foo" />
  </myobject>
</root>
```

When it's deserialized, I need the instance of `resource` referenced in the property of the `myobject` instance to be the same object created during the deserialization of the `resources` collection. Also, if possible I don't want to have to output the full serialization of the `resource` instance in `myobject`, only the name.

Is there any way of doing this? Right now I'm considering resorting to having a separate string property for serialization purposes that gets the relevant object from `root` when the deserializer sets the property, but that means giving `myobject` a reference to the `root` that contains it, and I was hoping to avoid that coupling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with `XmlSerializer`, because it doesn't handle object references.

If you don't have any constraint on the generated schema, you could use `DataContractSerializer`, which also serializes to XML but supports references. To use `DataContractSerializer`, each type must have a `DataContract` attribute, and each member you want to serialize must have a `DataMember` attribute :

```
[DataContract(Name = "root")]
public class root
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<resource> resources { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public myobject myobject { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class myobject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public resource resource { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "resource", IsReference = true)]
public class resource
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string anotherattribute { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string content { get; set; }
}

...

var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(root));
using (var xwriter = XmlWriter.Create(fileName))
{
    serializer.WriteObject(xwriter, r);
}
```

Note the `IsReference = true` for the `resource` class: that's what makes the serializer handle this class by reference. In the generated XML, each `resource` instance is only serialized once:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
  <myobject>
    <name>objName</name>
    <resource z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
      <anotherattribute>value</anotherattribute>
      <content>data</content>
      <name>foo</name>
    </resource>
  </myobject>
  <resources>
    <resource z:Ref="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
    <resource z:Id="i2" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
      <anotherattribute>value</anotherattribute>
      <content>more data</content>
      <name>bar</name>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</root>
```

Comment: The problem here is that the full deserialization of `resource` objects should be within the `resources` tag, never within a `myobject` tag. I suspect this is probably easy to sort simply by making sure that `resources` is serialized first, however. Also, I can't have extra attributes for Id and Ref in it, it's already got the name to use as a reference.

Comment: Indeed, you can change the order in which the properties are serialized. And like I said, this solution only works if you don't care about the XML schema... If you want it to be exactly as you described in your question, I think you will have to handle the serialization manually by implementing IXmlSerializable